# How to locate/show the map continent wise in jvectormap

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, jvectormap

I am currently using jvector map, when I hover each countries its default label show each country name. But, I want to choose regions based on the continent selection (World Map).

For Example :

In default the World Map,

when I hover the countries (**USA, Canada, Mexico, Brazil, Bolivia** etc..) its displays country name but instead of country name I want to show the Label as **America** and also the complete america region needs to get highlight.

In the same scenario for **EUROPE, ASIA** continents also.

Please kindly help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = {
    "countries" : [
               {
               "name" : "Brazil",
               "code" : "BR",
               "pGdp" : "6938",
               "cGdp" : "1313590",
               "pop" : "196342587",
               "continent" : "America"
               },
               {
               "name" : "United States",
               "code" : "US",
               "pGdp" : "45845",
               "cGdp" : "13843825",
               "pop" : "303824646",
               "continent" : "America"
               }
              ]
}

var countryData = [];

jQuery.each(data.countries, function() {
    countryData[this.code] = this[.pGdp];
});
```

jvm config...

```
series : {
    regions : [ {
        values : countryData,
        scale : [ '#C8EEFF', '#0071A4' ],
        normalizeFunction : 'polynomial'
    } ]
},
onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
    //search through data to find the selected country by it's code
    var country = $.grep(data.countries, function(obj, index) {
    return obj.code == code;
    })[0]; //snag the first one
    if (country != undefined) {
        el.html(el.html() + "<br/><b>Code: </b>" +country.code + "<br/><b>Continent : </b> " + country.continent);
    }
}
```